# Laravel how to use Enum in blade

Tags: laravel, enums

I am working on a laravel project, I have a db with the column named "status", the value for "status" is 1,2,3, I wanna the status value on the ui is converted to active, inactive, pending
here is the model.php file:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Enums\CompanyLabel\StatusEnum;    

class CompanyLabel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'status',
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'status' => StatusEnum::class,
    ];
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->whereIn('company_labels.status', StatusEnum::getCompanyLabelStatus());
    }
}
```

here is the StatusEnum file:
namespace App\Models\Enums\CompanyLabel;

```
enum StatusEnum: int
{
    case Active = 1;
    case Inactive = 2;
    case Pending = 3;

    public function str(): string
    {
        return match ($this) {
            self::Active => 'Active',
            self::Inactive => 'Inactive',
            self::Pending => 'Pending',
        };
    }

    public static function getCompanyLabelStatus()
    {
        return [
            self::Active->value => self::Active->str(),
            self::Inactive->value => self::Inactive->str(),
            self::Pending->value => self::Pending->str(),
        ];
    }
}
```

the status of datatable on the ui is still numeric rather than the corresponding string, can you please help me to figure it out? Many THX!

UPDATE:
here is the code to show datatable:

```
$records = MyTable::whereIn('mytable.status',array(1,2))
           ->select('mytable.status')  
            ->get();
$dataArray = array();
        foreach ($records as $record) {
            $dataArray[] = array(
                'status'  => $record->status,
            );
        }

        $response = array(
            "aaData" => $dataArray
        );
        
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 0,
            'data' => $response,
            'message' => 'Success'
        ]);
```

Comment: How are you outputting it on your frontend?

Comment: @geertjanknapen emm I use datatable in the blade to put the datatable on the ui parge

Comment: Show us in code how you do that

Comment: @geertjanknapen HI, I just updated my code, please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Would it not be as easy as `StatusEnum::from($record->status)->str()` in your foreach?

Comment: @geertjanknapen sry I cannot write it in the controller file directly. I guess maybe the reason is that I didn't use the str() function when I tried to use 'status'

Answer (score 0):

The value that shows up in your datable is correct, since the value that shows up is directly the value from your DB.

In the datatable youll need to call ->str() on the prop.

Could you post your datatable, this helps with helping you!

Comment: thanks for your answer,I just updated my datable in the main question body part, please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: i was referring to your blade file